# Find and highlight Misspelled words in a text file in Python(client-server model)

Tags: python, sockets, client-server, read-write, misspelling

I am new to StackOverflow. I was trying to complete some college assignment regarding misspelled words in Python.
But I am stuck with below requirement:-

I wanted to upload a text file from client to server which has some misspelled words. I have been trying to use read and write option but not able to get the desired output.Server should already have a lexicon of commonly misspelled words with it for comparison purpose.

Input :- Hllo I m nw to Pyton Coding. Ned some help.

Output:-  [Hllo] i [m] [nw] to [Pyton] Coding. [Ned] some help.

Could someone help as to what should i use to get this thing done.

I cannot share the exact code yet due to professor restrictions. But i have been able to solve the problem with Open and find statements. Just a query..is it possible to do with some other command to make use of less commands.

Comment: Can you share what you already tried? Please, also remove the part that are not related to you question. Ability to split problem into subproblems is crucial for an engineer.

Comment: I cannot share the exact code yet due to professor restrictions. But i have been able to solve the problem with Open and find statements. Just a query..is it possible to do with some other function to make use of fewer commands.

Comment: If you have been able to solve the problem with open and find statements, then what exactly do you need to solve? Is your professor requiring you to use less/other commands?

Comment: i just wanted to know if there is any other way to do it as well. Apart from using find open statements?